# Can't resolve './react' in

Tags: reactjs, resolve, npm-start

Not sure if this is a bug?

Module not found: Can't resolve './react' in /Users/idea/hjgkh/robotsf/src
even though I checked like  hundreds  of times

why am I keep getting this "Can't resolve './react' in" whenever Npm start.

Can someone please me help out here.

---

```
import React from './react';

const SearchBox =() => {
    return (
        <div className = 'pa2'> 
        <input
        className = 'pa3 ba b--green bg lightest-blue' 
        type = 'Search' 
        placeholder = 'Search Robots'
        />
        </div>
        );
}
export default SearchBox;
```

Comment: It's a bug in your code, not react or npm. `import React from './react';` should be `import React from 'react';`. Its a node module, not a local file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React should be in your node_modules directory, leave out the dot from the import statement:

`import React from 'react'`

Answer (score 0):

Many possible reasons - most likely the package is not there, or the path to it is incorrect.

1. Try `import React from 'react'`. Some setups will alias directly to
   the node_modules folder and require absolute paths to work.
2. Are you
   using Webpack? Make sure the project is setup correctly [Webpack +
   React](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/babel/)
3. Is react actually installed? Is it listed in package.json and
   have you installed it with `npm install`? Check [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) documentation as well.

Comment: import React from 'react; ' it worked thank you, yeah react actually installed